# Siddhi PMML Extension - Installation error

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-cep

I'm trying to install Siddhi PMML Extension from WSO2 DAS as described [here][1].
I downloaded archive p2-repo.zip, added repository WSO2 GPL Feature Repository. I have an error when I try to install the extension:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon GPL - Siddhi PMML Extension Feature 2.0.4 (org.wso2.siddhi.gpl.extension.pmml.feature.group 2.0.4) Missing requirement: pmml-evaluator 1.1.16.wso2v1 (pmml-evaluator 1.1.16.wso2v1) requires 'package com.google.common.base [15.0.0,18.0.0]' but it could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon GPL - Siddhi PMML Extension Feature 2.0.4 (org.wso2.siddhi.gpl.extension.pmml.feature.group 2.0.4) To: pmml-evaluator [1.1.16.wso2v1]

At the same time, I have no problem during installation other extentions (Siddhi NLP, R,...). How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what it the cep/das version?

Comment: wso2das-3.1.0 and org.wso2.siddhi.gpl.extension.pmml_2.0.4

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced the same problem. Try build the p2-repo from building the P2 repositories. It worked for me.

- Download the repositories  and build them using `mvn clean install` command in the following order.

  1. orbit
  2. siddhi
  3. carbon-event-processing
- Copy the generated P2 repository in carbon-event-processing/repository/target/p2-repo into a local directory in your machine.

Then add this folder as a repository to DAS.